# Qt passing hex value as an pointer and accessing it

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, hex

In the below program, I am trying to pass hexadecimal value to CRC16 function and do some calculations on it. But in the line (cc = 0xff & *ptr;) instead of ANDing the entire value of ptr only the first value is used. Can any one point out the mistake I am making here.
Thanks.

```
unsigned int crcValues[256];

unsigned int CRC16(unsigned int crc ,unsigned char *ptr)
{
    unsigned char tmp;
    unsigned char cc;
    cc = 0xff & ((unsigned int)*ptr);
    tmp = ((crc >> 8) ^ cc);

    crc = (crc << 8) ^ crcValues[tmp & 0xff];
    crc = crc & 0xffff;
    return crc;

}

void CRCCorrectionCode()
{
    unsigned int crc;
    int i = 0;
    int j;

    for(int c = 0;c < 256; c++)
    {
        crc = 0;
        j = c;
        c = c << 8;
        for(int j = 0;j < 8;j++){
            if((crc ^ c) & 0x8000)
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ poly;
            else
                crc = crc << 1;
            c = c << 1;
        }
        c = j;
        crcValues[i] = crc;
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    CRCCorrectionCode();
    QString tmpString = QString("0x%1").arg(254, 2, 16, QLatin1Char('0'));;
    int crc = 0;
    CRC16(crc,(unsigned char* )tmpString.toLatin1().data());
}
```

Comment: Is this the real code?  What's `j` in `tmpString[j]`?

Comment: @G.M. Sorry, I have edited the question.

Comment: 48 is the code of '0' ;)  your first char of '0x254' string. And this is not crc16 function.

Comment: Yes, I removed some lines from the code. The program contains many functions.

Comment: BTW, Qt has a CRC 16  already: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#qChecksum

Comment: "the entire value of ptr", as used at  `cc = 0xff & *ptr;` is an `unsigned char`, not a sequence of chars.

Comment: @drescherjm I have added included the full CRC calculations.

Comment: @Ripi2 Yes, I get it. Is there a way I can achieve it.

Comment: @Som If you know the length of the sequence, then it's a matter of several `&` and `<<` operations